# Laravel: File::allFiles() removing diacritics from file paths, how to preserve them?

Tags: php, laravel, diacritics

I'm using `File::allFiles()` to get all of the files from the given directory.

```
public function syncData(){
    $images = $this->getAllImages();
    dd($images);
}

public function getAllImages(){
    return File::allFiles(env('SYNC_FOLDER'));
}
```

After retrieving all images, i'm moving them to storage directory, but `allFiles()` method is removing diacritics from pathname string which makes them invalid. Original file path looks something like this `D:\Tumblr\Jogilė Verbickaitė.jpg`, but after retrieving images, diacritics are removed from the filenames.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => SplFileInfo {#205 ▼
    -relativePath: ""
    -relativePathname: "Jogile Verbickaite.jpg"
    path: "D:\Tumblr"
    filename: "Jogile Verbickaite.jpg"
    basename: "Jogile Verbickaite.jpg"
    pathname: "D:\Tumblr\Jogile Verbickaite.jpg"
    extension: "jpg"
    realPath: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

How can i preserve them to avoid invalid path?